# Unable to use ReactNative Navigation (Stack) on Android project

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am building a mobile application for both Android and IOS platforms using ReactNative. I am using React Navigation, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started for navigating between screens. I installed the libraries running the following commands.

- `npm install @react-navigation/native`
- `npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`
- `npm install @react-navigation/native-stack`

After I installed the packages, I run the following command to run the app on the Android device/ Emulator.
When I run the command, I get the following errors.

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:5344) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 1030 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin
w: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaView.kt: (50, 23): 'getter for uiImplementation: UIImplementation!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
50 actionable tasks: 35 executed, 15 up-to-date
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6c9a7a42c61ba7a5c65cc3e7d4f8eb18/transformed/jetified-react-native-0.69.0-debug-api.jar!/META-INF/ReactAndroid_debug.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/93284af1ff4aef981299aa5f71aeea44/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c31e8d21c519bec0fb80f130fce46632/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d513ea33b864f72616712d89ad44f7df/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (22, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (28, 32): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (33, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (38, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (42, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (46, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (48, 32): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (53, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (54, 28): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (58, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (59, 45): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (60, 32): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (63, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (65, 32): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/CustomSearchView.kt: (69, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/FragmentBackPressOverrider.kt: (15, 57): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/FragmentBackPressOverrider.kt: (19, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/FragmentBackPressOverrider.kt: (25, 36): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/FragmentBackPressOverrider.kt: (26, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/LifecycleHelper.kt: (9, 68): Unresolved reference: HashMap
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/LifecycleHelper.kt: (22, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/LifecycleHelper.kt: (23, 18): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/LifecycleHelper.kt: (31, 23): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/LifecycleHelper.kt: (32, 32): Unresolved reference: mViewToLifecycleMap[view]
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/LifecycleHelper.kt: (32, 32): No set method providing array access
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/LifecycleHelper.kt: (42, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/LifecycleHelper.kt: (47, 20): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/RNScreensPackage.kt: (18, 16): Unresolved reference: emptyList
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/RNScreensPackage.kt: (22, 9): Unresolved reference: listOf
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (54, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (71, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (72, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (74, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (81, 22): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (85, 26): Not enough information to infer type variable T
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (85, 65): Unresolved reference: java
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (108, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (113, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (120, 21): Unresolved reference: until
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (122, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (141, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (142, 20): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (147, 18): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (150, 28): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (151, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (162, 19): Unresolved reference: let
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (162, 44): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (162, 65): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (168, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (169, 37): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (176, 36): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (178, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (179, 23): Unresolved reference: let
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (179, 48): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (179, 63): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (179, 84): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (186, 36): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (188, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (189, 23): Unresolved reference: let
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (189, 48): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (189, 64): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (196, 36): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
The class is loaded from /Users/waihein/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/347daadc4577e97ea182fd1bbd88604c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/waihein/Desktop/Code/RNRestaurantAutomatorManager/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt: (198, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, this problem always appears after installing react-native-screens, the solution that usually works for me is:

1. Go to project-> android -> build.gradle *(**note:** not app/build.gradle)*
2. [As you see in the screenshot, add this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnYKp.png) *(**note**: The version is whatever it shows in error, for you it is 1.6.0 so add the same line)*
3. [As you see in the screenshot, add this line aswell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsSrz.png)
4. Hopefully this works!

Comment: This work for me, Thank you so much as I was searching for solution for a long time,
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is gonna work in your case but you can give it a shot. Go to your node_modules/react-native-photo-editor/android/build.gradle.
Remove SNAPSHOT from -> implementation 'com.github.prscX:photo-editor-android:master-SNAPSHOT'. And then run your app.

[Reference](https://github.com/prscX/react-native-photo-editor/issues/181#issuecomment-1027987736)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by deleting the .gradle folder on my Mac and then run the build again